# Weird error in my Comparator class, eclipse calling it syntax but syntax seems correct

Tags: java, comparator

I'm getting a weird syntax error in a comparator class that will load in song names and sort them lexicographically. The syntax is seemingly correct, but I am unsure about what is happening as Eclipse is giving me this error:

Multiple markers at this line

- Syntax error on token ",", ( expected
- Syntax error on token "(", { expected
- Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block
- Syntax error, insert ";" to complete 
  ClassBodyDeclarations
- Syntax error on token ",", ( expected
- Syntax error, insert ";" to complete  ClassBodyDeclarations
- Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block
- Breakpoint:SongComparator

I haven't tried much to fix this, I can't really tell where to start. Coming here hoping to get a little insight on what the issue is.

Here is my code:

```
package cmsc256;

import bridges.data_src_dependent.Song;
import bridges.connect.DataFormatter;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class SongComparator implements Comparator<Song>(Song o1, Song o2) {

    public int compare(Song o1, Song o2) {

        Song placeHolder;

        if (o1.compareTo(o2) > 1) {
            //do nothing
        }
        else if(o1.compareTo(o2) == 0) {
            //do nothing
        }
        else if (o1.compareTo(o2) < 1) {
            o1 = placeHolder;
            o1 = o2;
            o2 = placeHolder;
        }
    }

    public String getSongsByArtist(String artist) {
        return "";
    }

}
```

The error occurs on the class declaration - specifically in the parameters. Both parenthesis, the open bracket, and the comma separating the parameters are all underlined.

Comment: you are not returning anything in `compare` method

Comment: what is the need for placeholder here. What sorting are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I'm eventually going to be sorting alphabetically by swapping each of the songs on the arrayList.  This class is for a school project and is required to use, though it's not necessary to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least three issues:

1. You are not returning anything in your `compare` method
2. `public class SongComparator implements Comparator<Song>(Song o1, Song o2) {` should be just `public class SongComparator implements Comparator<Song> {`
3. You need to initialize `placeHolder` before you can assign it to another variable
4. (Potentially): You can only call `compareTo` on `Song` if that class implements it (usually by implementing the `Comparable` interface). But then you probably wouldn't need to write a custom `SongComparator`.

Here is some skeleton code to get you started:

```
class SongComparator implements Comparator<Song> {

    public int compare(Song o1, Song o2) {
        // Implement your comparison logic here
        return o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString());
    }

    public String getSongsByArtist(String artist) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so most of this is solved when I actually have the method completed.  Thank you for the help :) I'm pretty new to this.